# PHP code in viewing a pdf file from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How to view .pdf file in a webpage using PHP? The pdf file is in a mysql database. Thanks.

Comment: Is the file itself in the database, or is the filename in the database? And how is it stored? Just as binary data or in any other way?

Answer (score 2):

If you echo the contents from the database to the browser and provide the appropriate content type through HTTP headers you're done!

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
echo $pdf_from_database;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The pdf file is in a mysql database

Shocking! They are rarely good results in saving files in a database. Directories are better storing places for files.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename='document.pdf'");
header("Content-length: ".strlen($binary_contents_from_database));

echo $binary_contents_from_database;
```

If a PDF plug-in is available for the browser, then the document will be displayed inline, otherwise it will be given as a download.